# How to make a scrollable div scroll on click and mouseover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Using the markup below how would I get the "#content" div to scroll up or down when I click or hover over the "#scrollUp" or "#scrollDown" anchor tag. Scrolling should be smooth preferably. If clicked it should scroll a specific amount (for touch devices) if mouseover it can scroll until mouseout.

```
 <style>  
         #content {
         overflow:auto;
         height: 50px; /*could be whatever*/
                 }
  </style>

<a id="scrollUp" href="#">up</a>
<a id="scrollDown" href="#">down</a>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="content">

  <ul>
    <li>some content here</li>
    <li>some content here</li>
    <li>some content here</li>
    <li>some content here</li>
    <li>some content here</li>
    <li>some content here</li>
  </ul>

 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to accomplish a smooth-scrolling effect on `click` or `mouseover`:

```
var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$("#scrollUp").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    // Cancel scrolling continuously:
    scrolling = false;
});


$("#scrollDown").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    scrolling = false;
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 1, function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            // If we want to keep scrolling, call the scrollContent function again:
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/s5mgX/

*(You'll have to disable the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to see the effects of the `click` event handler properly)*

How it works:

- Uses the `animate` function mentioned above to scroll smoothly by a specified amount on click.
- Uses a flag to enable continuous scrolling on when the link's `mouseover` event handler is called, and disable scrolling when the link's `mouseout` event handler.
- When `scrollContent` is called, if the `scrolling` flag is still `true` after the animation is completed, animate again in the same direction.  The callback function parameter of `animate` allows us to take an action after animation has completed.

Comment: Andrew - you rock. Great explanation and solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript instead of jQuery for this task.  Google the function `scrollBy()` as in `window.scrollBy()`

Comment: `scrollBy()` is only available on the window. I think he is asking to scroll a div.