# Buttons to scroll a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to make a div scroll up or down when I mouseover an up or down arrow button. Does anyone know a plugin (jquery is ok) that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571867/how-to-make-a-scrolable-div-scroll-on-click-and-mouseover-using-jquery) they seem to be trying to implement the same sort of functionality.

Comment: Thanks, found the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The [ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) JQuery plugin should do the trick!

Comment: I was trying to use that but I couldn't work out how to make the div continously scroll when I moused over the button.

Comment: You should probably go with Jacindas suggestion then. From the plugin site: "Smooth Div Scroll does not limit the scrolling to distinct steps"