# Customize scrolling with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to achieve the following look for a box that can scroll up and down:

[image: look]

and not the scroll bar on the side. Is this possible that when they click on the up arrow or hover over it, it scrolls up and the same for the down arrow? as well as if they use the scrolling button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a simple example, I hope it can help you.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/sz35s/3/)

The only code jQuery you need is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#prev').click(function(){
        $('li:last').detach().prependTo('ul').css({'margin-top':'-=100px'})
        $('li:first').stop().animate({'margin-top':'0px'},1000)
    })

    $('#next').click(function(){
        $('li:first').stop().animate({'margin-top':'-=100px'},1000,function(){
            $(this).detach().css({'margin-top':'0px'}).appendTo('ul')
            })
    })
})
</script>
```

If you want to build pure css arrows visit this site: [link](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

And your result will be [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/q5NYS/)

Sometimes the simplicity is the best thing..by

Answer (score 0):

This question provides an jQuery Solution for Scrolling a `<div>` element on click.
It seems to be flexible so you can customize the scroll step for each click.

[How to make a scrolable div scroll on click and mouseover using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571867/how-to-make-a-scrolable-div-scroll-on-click-and-mouseover-using-jquery)