# Make a jumbotron automatically resize according to screen size (also add a scroll button)

Tags: html, css

I want to make the image fill the screen.

I have looked at a few ways to do stuff like this but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I also want to add in a scroll function to the "learn more" hyperlink that will smoothly scroll the page down.

I have changed the project to be a placeholder and uploaded it to CodePen.

Here it is:

(also note that it also uses typekit which came with my photoshop license so it may not work for you, and the header text is white not grey in my wampp setup.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgRKoV

```
    <html>

    <head>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css">
      <script src="https://use.typekit.net/pzl7njn.js"></script>
      <script>try{Typekit.load({ async: false });}catch(e){}</script>
      <script src=JS/jquery.scrollex></script>
      <script src=JS/jquery.scrollex></script>
      </head>

      <body>
      <div class="menu-wrap">
      <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dropdown <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4 &amp; 5</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
            <p>Dolor sit Amet.</p>
            <a href="#one" class="next">Start</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <section id=one>
            <div class="Thumbnails">
            <div class="container">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed pulvinar neque, gravida ultrices sem. Cras congue dapibus tortor, a condimentum magna pharetra at. Quisque scelerisque ullamcorper eros, eu vulputate justo aliquet id. Praesent
          auctor interdum odio vel suscipit. Integer placerat vitae odio tempus commodo. Morbi mollis ex justo, nec pulvinar lectus finibus at. Maecenas scelerisque est in nulla viverra, vel cursus elit sollicitudin.</p>
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="http://www.engraversnetwork.com/files/placeholder.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </section>
      <div class="learn-more">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed pulvinar neque, gravida ultrices sem. Cras congue dapibus tortor, a condimentum magna pharetra at. Quisque scelerisque ullamcorper eros, eu vulputate justo aliquet id. Praesent
            auctor interdum odio vel suscipit. Integer placerat vitae odio tempus commodo. Morbi mollis ex justo, nec pulvinar lectus finibus at. Maecenas scelerisque est in nulla viverra, vel cursus elit sollicitudin.</p>
          <p><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed pulvinar neque, gravida ultrices sem. Cras congue dapibus tortor, a condimentum magna pharetra at. Quisque scelerisque ullamcorper eros, eu vulputate justo aliquet id. Praesent
            auctor interdum odio vel suscipit. Integer placerat vitae odio tempus commodo. Morbi mollis ex justo, nec pulvinar lectus finibus at. Maecenas scelerisque est in nulla viverra, vel cursus elit sollicitudin.</p>
          <p><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed pulvinar neque, gravida ultrices sem. Cras congue dapibus tortor, a condimentum magna pharetra at. Quisque scelerisque ullamcorper eros, eu vulputate justo aliquet id. Praesent
            auctor interdum odio vel suscipit. Integer placerat vitae odio tempus commodo. Morbi mollis ex justo, nec pulvinar lectus finibus at. Maecenas scelerisque est in nulla viverra, vel cursus elit sollicitudin.</p>
          <p><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450849608880-6f787542c88a?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=1000&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925');
  height: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 84px;  
  font-family: "industry",sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #000;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 24px;
font-family: "industry",sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 1000;
text-shadow: 3px 3px #000;
color: #fff;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}
.Thumbnails {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
.Thumbnails h2 {
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.Thumbnails p {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

/*----- Responsive Nav Start Credit - http://tinyurl.com/qepfqon -----*/

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    background:#DAE6EB;
    margin:0px auto
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    opacity:5;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'industry';
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#98a1a4;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#414546;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#98a1a4;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    background:#98a1a4B;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
        font-size: 18px;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#98a1a4;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the following CSS for the 'jumbotron' image:

```
height: 1000px;
```

If you'd like to make the image the same size as the screen try using 100% or 100vh instead.

This should do the trick:

```
.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  height:100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding:100px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question - I believe that this has already been answered here:

[How to make a scrolable div scroll on click and mouseover using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571867/how-to-make-a-scrolable-div-scroll-on-click-and-mouseover-using-jquery)

Comment: Thank you, I will be trying that out now.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, 100vh makes it about the same size as 1000px on my screen, maybe a little smaller, and 100% makes it a banner on my screen. I am trying out the scroll thing now.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestions but none were what I was looking for. I will probably end up making a separate question for the scroll bit, but I just want to know how I would go about intergrating the Scrollex jqeury script (google it) into my website. Thanks for your time.

Comment: see my edit (note: you'll need to remove the height 1000px from the .jumbotron class). That should make the image fill the screen as you asked.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the white bar in the bottom of the screen when using your edit is exactly the height of the windows taskbar which auto-hides for me... could this be related?

Comment: Now I have another problem... the dropdown menu doesnt work... I'll experiment with it tomorrow... I'm going now... I'll come have a look at what is suggested tomorrow. Big thanks in advance to everyone.